# How can I stop states from resetting to initial state when page changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Hello!** I am having some difficulties with the states of my quiz. Every time I click one of the three option buttons (from the JSX), the states [questionsAnswered] and [correctAnswers] get properly incremented, but only for a brief second before the page "refreshes" and the states return to their initial state. **I need to stop these two states from returning to their initial states when changes are made to the page *(specifically: when buttons are clicked)*.** Is there any way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import Logo from '../Components/Logo'
import Game_ById from '../Components/Game_ById';
import { QuizContext } from '../Contexts/QuizContext';
import IQuizContext from '../Interfaces/IQuizContext';

import '../Quiz.css';

const Quiz_Play = () => {

    const {questions} = useContext(QuizContext) as IQuizContext; // get all questions from contexts

    const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(false);

      useEffect(() => {
        if(questions.length > 0){
            generateRandomNumber()
            nextQuestion()
            setFirstRender(true);
        }
    
        return () => {
          if (window.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
             window.location.href = "/quiz"
          }
    
        };
      }, [firstRender, questions]);

    const [questionNum, setQuestionNum] = useState<number>(0)
    const [questionText, setQuestionText] = useState<string>("")
    const [questionImageId, setQuestionImageId] = useState<number | undefined>(0)
    const [questionOptions, setQuestionOptions] = useState<string[]>([])
    const [questionCorrect, setQuestionCorrect] = useState<string>("")

    // these two states keep resetting back to 0 (initial state) when I click a button
    const [questionsAnswered, setQuestionsAnswered] = useState<number>(0)
    const [correctAnswers, setCorrectAnswers] = useState<number>(0)

    const [random, setRandom] = useState<number>(0)

    const generateRandomNumber = () => {
        const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)
        setRandom(rand)
    }
    
    const nextQuestion = () => {
        
        generateRandomNumber()

        const q = questions[random]

        setQuestionNum(questionNum+1)
        setQuestionImageId(q.gameId)
        setQuestionText(q.question)
        setQuestionOptions(q.options)
        setQuestionCorrect(q.correct)
    }

    const chooseOption = (e : any) => {

        console.log("current value is :" + e.currentTarget.value)
    
        if(questionsAnswered != undefined){
            setQuestionsAnswered(questionsAnswered+1)
        }
        
        if(e.currentTarget.value === questionCorrect){
            setCorrectAnswers(correctAnswers+1)
        }
    }
  
  return (
    <div>
        
        <Logo />

        <div className="wrapper">
            <h1 className="quizInfo_h1"> Question {questionNum} </h1>
            <h2 className="quizQuestion_h2 text-align-center">{questionText}</h2>
            <p className="correctCounter_p text-align-center no-margin "><span style={{color: '#f2c112'}}>{correctAnswers}</span>/{questionsAnswered}</p>
            
            <div className="quizImage">
                <Game_ById id={questionImageId}/>
            </div>

        </div>
        
        <div className="quiz-options">
            <form>
                <button className="btn small-med-btn quiz-option-btn" id="option-1" onClick={chooseOption} value={questionOptions[0]}>{questionOptions[0]}</button>
                <button className="btn small-med-btn quiz-option-btn" id="option-2" onClick={chooseOption} value={questionOptions[1]}>{questionOptions[1]}</button>
                <button className="btn small-med-btn quiz-option-btn" id="option-3" onClick={chooseOption} value={questionOptions[2]}>{questionOptions[2]}</button>   
            </form>    
        </div>

        <p style={{marginTop: 10, color:"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"}} className="text-align-center">
            Don't want to play anymore? Feeling like a <Link to="/quiz" className="yellowlink">coward</Link>?
        </p>

        

    </div>
  );
}

export default Quiz_Play;
```

I have read around online and **I assume this could be fixed with the useRef hook**, somehow? I have tried to implement something of the kind after seing some posts about it but I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance to anyone taking the time to help. It's greatly appreciated

**Also,** let me know if you need me to provide additional information in order for you to assist.

Comment: You're setting the window location manually instead of using react-router. The page reloads so your current JS context goes away. You **could** use local/sessionStorage, or use react-router.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the comment, but the line of code you are referencing to redirects the user to another page called /Pages/Quiz on route /quiz . This is not what's causing the problem I'm trying to address here.

Comment: Could you point out which states that have this issue?

Comment: @Disco basically the only states I need to maintain throughout the quiz are questionsAnswered and correctAnswer.
But I guess all of them go back to the state defined inside their parentheses, for example: const [questionOptions, setQuestionOptions] = useState<string[]>([]) will return to an empty array, but immediately after it is injected with data from the {questions} array from Context. But questionsAnswered and correctAnswers are not being set in nextQuestion() , therefore they go back to 0

Comment: @Disco but to directly answer your questions. The states that have this issue (hence the states im trying to ensure are not being reset) are: questionsAnswered and correctAnswers

Comment: type="button" or remove your form element.

Comment: @KevinB has the correct answer here, the buttons submits the form. Just remove the wrapping form. 
And one extra thing dont use the current state like this.  `setQuestionsAnswered(questionsAnswered+1)` 
If you need the current state use the function version instead:
`setQuestionsAnswered((current) => current+1)`

Comment: @KevinB dang, I did not think of this. I will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: @Disco Thanks alot! I will try all of this :)

Comment: Thanks guys. Turns out, just like @KevinB said, when I removed the form element the issue disappeared